# JAVA, display phrase in increasing font sizes in a frame

Tags: java, jframe

I am having an issue getting this code to run properly. It compiles and initially the frame displays properly. The problem is that when I manually re-size the frame by either maximizing or by dragging the side of the frame over, the text disappears. I am using jGRASP, not sure if that is the issue or not. The code seems to make sense to me, and like I said, it compiles(I know that does not necessarily make it right). I'm still a newbie at this so if anyone can point me in the right direction I would be very appreciative.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class JFontSizes extends JFrame {
   int x = 5;
   int y = 50;
   String homework = "This is the first homework assignment";
   public JFontSizes() {
      super("Increasing Font Sizes");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);     
   }   
   public void paint(Graphics brush) {
      super.paint(brush);
      // This works sometimes. I am not sure if it is a jGRASP issue or something else.
      // If I resize the frame, the text disappears, and I cannot get the text to start at the top of the frame
      for(int n = 6; n<= 20; ++n) {
         brush.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, n));
         brush.drawString(homework, x, y);
         y += 15;
      }   
   }              
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFontSizes frame = new JFontSizes();
      frame.setSize(400, 500);
      frame.setVisible(true);      
   }   
}
```

Comment: It's generally discouraged to paint directly to the frame, instead, use a `JPanel` and use it to perform your custom painting by overriding its `paintComponent` method, see [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When first time paint() is called the value of y was 5. And it is incremented in a loop. So that before leaving paint() its value will be 275.

But when you resize your frame paint() is called again and this time the value of y is 275 and when `brush.drawString(homework, x, y);` is called the `homework` is printed at 275px bottom from top left corner.

So what you need to do is re-initialize y every time :

```
public void paint(Graphics brush) {
    y = 50;
    ....
```

**Edit :**
As commented by [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr) you should override `paintComponent(...)` instead of `paint(...)` until you have some specific reason to override paint().
And you mean you are not able to print text at top (even in beginning) then it is because you had initialized y with 50. Which means the text will be drawn at 50px from top.

Comment: Answers why the painting disappears (+1). However, painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method of a JPanel and then you add the panel to the frame. `I cannot get the text to start at the top of the frame` You are telling it to start at 50. You should start at 0. Then you should use the `Graphics.getFontMetrics()` method. The `FontMetrics` class will give the maximum height of the Font.  Then before you paint the string you add this value to the y value. Now all the fonts will be evenly painted in the panel.